# Cleanmgr with command or batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-10, command-prompt

I am trying to build a maintenance script for Windows 10. This shell or command line should operate multiple maintenance operations at a time.
I cannot find any batch demo of this type on StackOverflow so I share it here.

Answer (score 0):

It uses Windows 10 Clean Manager cleanmgr.exe
It creates a cleaning profile, number 777, that is registered and can be called with cleanmgr /sagerun:777

You must launch this batch with Administrator privileges to modify registry.

```
:: Disk cleanup
echo 1/10 ^| Windows is cleaning his mess ...

REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Active Setup Temp Folders" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Content Indexer Cleaner" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Downloaded Program Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Internet Cache Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Memory Dump Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Microsoft_Event_Reporting_2.0_Temp_Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Offline Pages Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Old ChkDsk Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Previous Installations" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
::REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Recycle Bin" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Remote Desktop Cache Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\ServicePack Cleanup" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Setup Log Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\System error memory dump files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\System error minidump files" /v StateFlags0777  /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Temporary Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Temporary Setup Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Temporary Sync Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Update Cleanup" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Upgrade Discarded Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\WebClient and WebPublisher Cache" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Windows Defender" /v StateFlags0777 /d 2 /t REG_DWORD /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Windows Error Reporting Archive Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Windows Error Reporting Queue Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f    
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Windows Error Reporting System Archive Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Windows Error Reporting System Queue Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Windows ESD installation files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Windows Upgrade Log Files" /v StateFlags0777 /t REG_DWORD /d 00000002 /f
cleanmgr /sagerun:777
echo OK
echo:
```

As I cannot find any help on StackOverflow to build this script, I share what I acheived to do.

You can then chain other system maintenance operations, like System file check sfc.exe.

To start using, copy-paste this script in a blank notepad and save as scriptName.cmd

```
:: System integrity
echo 2/10 ^| Windows file checking starting ...
%SystemRoot%\System32\sfc.exe /scannow
if not %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
   echo Erreurs détectées sur le disque !
   echo Démarrage de la réparation du système ...
   Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
) else (
  echo OK
)
echo:
```

Comment: Have you considered using a loop? _all of your value names, value types and value data are the same_. Also with a simple `Set` statement at the outset, your registry paths can be considerably shortened too. If there's a need for a script to be run 'as Administrator', you should really make your audience aware of it.

Comment: Good idea.
In fact it's still WIP. But we can always improve ;-)
Going for a loop then. I'll update as soon as I can

Comment: @Compo, are you confortable with loops in cmd ?

Comment: Djibe, comfortable enough to have seen an advantage in suggsting one.

Comment: @Compo, I mean, could you help me building one ?

Answer (score 0):

I've added to your idea here, including some loops that use 'arrays' (variable containing multiple strings separated with quotes and commas).

The first 'array' called "VOLUME_LOCATIONS" contains what you shared above (w/o "Recycle Bin") as an example.

Though the script is setup to capture all the subkeys that exists here:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches

This 'array' called "DYNAMIC_ARRAY_VOLUMES" can be reduced by a predefined 'array' called "OMITTED_LOCATIONS".
This dynamic approach accounts for new volumes/locations that may be added  in the future.

```
@echo off
REM This script loops through an array of volume cache locations in the registry and sets a flag
REM This replicates what is done via GUI by the command [ cleanmgr /sageset ] and then executes via [ cleanmgr /sagerun:# ]
REM This script requires to be run as an administrator - for Windows > Server 2008 (Or have cleanmgr added)
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET FLAG=StateFlags0777 && SET REG_VALUE=00000002
SET REG_LOC=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches
Set "NUM_ENTRIES=0" && Set "LAST_ENTRY=0"
SET VOLUME_LOCATIONS=("Active Setup Temp Folders", "Content Indexer Cleaner", "Downloaded Program Files", "Internet Cache Files", "Memory Dump Files", "Microsoft_Event_Reporting_2.0_Temp_Files", "Offline Pages Files", "Old ChkDsk Files", "Previous Installations", "Remote Desktop Cache Files", "ServicePack Cleanup", "Setup Log Files", "System error memory dump files", "System error minidump files", "Temporary Files", "Temporary Setup Files", "Temporary Sync Files", "Update Cleanup", "Upgrade Discarded Files", "WebClient and WebPublisher Cache", "Windows Defender", "Windows Error Reporting Archive Files", "Windows Error Reporting Queue Files", "Windows Error Reporting System Archive Files", "Windows Error Reporting System Queue Files", "Windows ESD installation files", "Windows Upgrade Log Files")
REM To dynamically create an array of ALL entries, then presumably omitting those undesired:
for /F "delims=" %%i IN ('reg query "%REG_LOC%"') do set /a "NUM_ENTRIES+=1"
echo There are %NUM_ENTRIES% entries in the registry.
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('reg query "%REG_LOC%"') do (
set /a "LAST_ENTRY+=1"
Set DYNAMIC_ARRAY_VOLUMES=!DYNAMIC_ARRAY_VOLUMES!, "%%~nxG"
Set DYNAMIC_ARRAY_VOLUMES[%%~nxG]=!LAST_ENTRY!
if !LAST_ENTRY! == 1 Set DYNAMIC_ARRAY_VOLUMES="%%~nxG"
if !LAST_ENTRY! == %NUM_ENTRIES% GOTO :ARRAY_BUILT
)
:ARRAY_BUILT
echo The following would be an all inclusive list of locations:
echo. && echo (%DYNAMIC_ARRAY_VOLUMES%) && echo.
REM The following array and 'for loop' sets and removes entries wished to omitted from cleanmanager cleanup
REM SET OMITTED_LOCATIONS=("Recycle Bin", "Windows Upgrade Log Files")
SET OMITTED_LOCATIONS=("")
REM For loop repeated to handle the last entry, if applicable, as it should only have a preceeding comma and space
for %%q in %OMITTED_LOCATIONS% do SET DYNAMIC_ARRAY_VOLUMES=!DYNAMIC_ARRAY_VOLUMES:%%q, =!
for %%q in %OMITTED_LOCATIONS% do SET DYNAMIC_ARRAY_VOLUMES=!DYNAMIC_ARRAY_VOLUMES:, %%q=!
echo The following would be a reduced list of locations: && echo (%DYNAMIC_ARRAY_VOLUMES%) && echo.

echo Adding registry values via array and loop, use the following line instead of the one after - if attempting dynamically
for %%i in (%DYNAMIC_ARRAY_VOLUMES%) do (
REM for %%i in %VOLUME_LOCATIONS% do (
ECHO REG ADD "%REG_LOC%\%%~i" /v %FLAG% /t REG_DWORD /d %REG_VALUE% /f
REG ADD "%REG_LOC%\%%~i" /v %FLAG% /t REG_DWORD /d %REG_VALUE% /f
)
echo. && echo The disk space for C: BEFORE running: && echo.  && fsutil volume diskfree c: && echo.
ECHO Running cleanmgr against the specified volume locations
ECHO "cleanmgr /sagerun:777"
cleanmgr /sagerun:777
echo. && echo The disk space for C: AFTER running: && echo.  && fsutil volume diskfree c: && echo.
REM To verify what exists for VolumeCaches in the registry, or to see changes before/after, run:
REM reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches
REM To return all the subkey values, add the '/s' argument, as seen below:
REM reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches /s
echo 
REM pause
exit /b
REM exit
```

The most challenging part here was accounting for the quotes and delimitation in to create and use the 'arrays'.  I'm guessing there's a better way, but this seems to work.
Also, on older servers, you may need to jump through a hoop by enabling ['Desktop Experience'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/disk-cleanup) to get cleanmgr.exe back in the Windows\System32 folder...

Why batch, why cleanmgr.exe?

- My company doesn't typically [enable Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7) on our servers.
- Cleanmgr incorporates Microsoft's way of cleaning the disk and
  there are significant differences rather than simply deleting
  temp/cache locations.  Specifically, I understand that current/recent
  data is omitted during deletion, [possibly ~7+days old](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/automatically-clear-temp-files-every-login-using-disk-cleanup-batch-file/)?

Comment: One problem with doing this in a loop is that some options use a different value e.g. Temporary Internet Files is 00000003

Comment: Thanks SS64, that's good to know.  Is there a lookup/reference to know what values are used?   One could append the value with an underscore to each volume location, then use a nested loop to split each string out - which has worked well for me for other scripts.

Comment: Correction: the default value for Temporary Internet Files is 00000002 but any non-zero value seems to have the same effect.